# JDA member.ban(); Doesn't Ban the member?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am having trouble with using member.ban() in JDA 4; when I call the cmd it doesn't send any error to console all it outputs is

> Successfully banned MB:[nicknamehere](U:[usernamehere [usersidhere]) / G:[GuildNameHere] [GuildIDHere))

This is the code that runs this

```
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(cogBotMain.prefix + "Ban") && event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)){
            Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replace("<@!", "").replace(">", ""));
            if(args.length < 3){
                //ERROR
                EmbedBuilder errorban = new EmbedBuilder();
                errorban.setTitle("Cog Bot - Syntax Error");
                errorban.setDescription("Please use the proper syntax: " + cogBotMain.prefix + "ban <mentionTheUser> <NumberMessagesToDelete> <Reason>");
                errorban.setColor(0xf56e6e);
                errorban.setFooter("Created by A Yoshi#1662");

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(errorban.build()).complete();
                errorban.clear();

            }else{
                String Banres = args[3];
                int BanTime = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

                if (member != null) {
                    member.ban(BanTime,Banres);
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Successfully banned " + member).complete();
                }




            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you forgot the `queue()` behind the `member.ban(BanTime,Banres);`